# Returning two sets of action in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So what i am doing is that i am displaying a list of categories in a page and each category contains a sublist of categories. I have a controller and it is returning the list of categories without the sublist of categories. how can i get the sublist showing from using the same controller.

**Controller:**

```
 public CourseIndexVw Get(int id)
    {
        var _types = new ElementTypesService().GetElementModelsForCourseIndex(id, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        var _courseIndexbyTypesVw = new CourseSectionsControllerHelper().CourseIndexTypeVw(id);
        _courseIndexbyTypesVw.Types = _types.ToList();
        var _activeType = _courseIndexbyTypesVw.Types.First();
        _courseIndexbyTypesVw.ActiveId = _activeType != null ? _activeType.Id : -1;
        return _courseIndexbyTypesVw;
    }
```

**GetElementModelsForCourseIndex:**

```
public List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> GetElementModelsForCourseIndex(int elementId, int userId, int depthLevel = 2)
        {
            List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> TypesName;
            ElementType type;
            using (var db = DataContextManager.AleStoredProcsContext)
            {

                TypesName = db.GetElementModelsForCourseIndex<ElementModelForCourseIndex>(elementId, userId, r => new ElementModelForCourseIndex{
                        Id = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.Id(r),
                        Identity = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.Identity(r)
                    }).OrderBy(n=>n.Identity).ToList();
            }
            foreach (ElementModelForCourseIndex typeContent in TypesName)
            {
                typeContent.Children = GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(elementId, userId, type.ModelId, depthLevel);
            }
        }
```

**GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex:**

```
    public List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(int elementId, int userId, ElementType typeId, int depthLevel = 2)
    {
        using (var db = DataContextManager.AleStoredProcsContext)
        {
            return db.GetElementWithCalendarAndPermsByModel<ElementModelForCourseIndex>(elementId, userId, typeId.Id, r => new ElementModelForCourseIndex
            {
                IdentityName = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.IdentityName(r),
                ValueString = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.ValueString(r),
                TimeReleased = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.TimeReleased(r),
                TimeDue = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.TimeReleased(r)
            }).OrderBy(i => i.IdentityName).ToList();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Current issue is with `typeContent.Children = GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(elementId, userId, type.ModelId, depthLevel);` The error i am getting is: the override method has invalid arguments
Any Help is appreciated and if i am missing any information let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your model and add a `children` property:

```
public class ElementModelForCourseIndex
{
    // *snip* your code
    public List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> Children {get; set;}
}
```

You could either get it within your current `GetElementModelsForCourseIndex` or use you helper method like this:

```
public List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> GetElementModelsForCourseIndex(int elementId, int userId, int depthLevel = 2)
    {
        List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> courses;
        using (var db = DataContextManager.AleStoredProcsContext)
        {
            courses =  db.GetElementModelsForCourseIndex<ElementModelForCourseIndex>(elementId, userId, r => new ElementModelForCourseIndex{
                    Id = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.Id(r),
                    Identity = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.Identity(r)
                }).OrderBy(n=>n.Identity).ToList();
        }
        for each(ElementModelForCourseIndex course in courses)
        {
            // here you are filling the Children. 
            //You need to check if the parameters are the correct ones. 
            // Since you haven't shown the actual model class, I'm only guessing the parameters
            course.Children = GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(elementId, userId, depthLevel);
        }
        return courses;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - i will go ahead and give this a try and let you know.

Comment: So for the `course.Children` i have to pass in the `typeId` which is of type `ElementType` - how can i pass that in properly for `GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex`

Comment: That depends on your situation / domain model / requirement. In the comment above that line, I said that you needed to figure that out, because there's no way we can know

Comment: ok thanks - as for my return statement - how will that look? I will need to return the children.