# override method has invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure why there is an error if anyone can make it clear for me that will be great.

```
public List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> GetElementModelsForCourseIndex(int elementId, int userId, int depthLevel = 2)
    {
        List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> TypesName;
        ElementType type = new ElementType();
        using (var db = DataContextManager.AleStoredProcsContext)
        {

            TypesName = db.GetElementModelsForCourseIndex<ElementModelForCourseIndex>(elementId, userId, r => new ElementModelForCourseIndex{
                    Id = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.Id(r),
                    Identity = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.Identity(r)
                }).OrderBy(n=>n.Identity).ToList();
        }
        foreach (ElementModelForCourseIndex typeContent in TypesName)
        {
            typeContent.Children = GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(elementId, userId, type.ModelId, depthLevel);
        }
    }

    public List<ElementModelForCourseIndex> GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(int elementId, int userId, ElementType typeId, int depthLevel = 2)
    {
        using (var db = DataContextManager.AleStoredProcsContext)
        {
            return db.GetElementWithCalendarAndPermsByModel<ElementModelForCourseIndex>(elementId, userId, typeId.Id, r => new ElementModelForCourseIndex
            {
                IdentityName = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.IdentityName(r),
                ValueString = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.ValueString(r),
                TimeReleased = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.TimeReleased(r),
                TimeDue = ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap.TimeReleased(r)
            }).OrderBy(i => i.IdentityName).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The error is in the top method with this line which needs to return a statement.

Comment: What is the type of `type.ModelId`. The method is expecting an `ElementType`.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390039/returning-two-sets-of-action-in-one-controller

Comment: If it is Something So Simple and Easy that people think to downvote - then why not help out instead maybe elaborate and share the knowledge. We don't all think and see things on the same level.

Comment: Wasn't me. ;) (+1'd to offset a bit - I don't think it's a bad question, but a bit difficult to determine the answer).

Comment: where is your **override**? `public override toString(){}` would be an override but `public toString()` is just a new methode ...

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
typeContent.Children = GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex(elementId, 
                       userId, type, depthLevel);
```

The third parameter is culprit. It takes `ElementType` and you are providing `type.ModelId` (which i guess is Integer)

Comment: I think he has an overload (the second function) that allows 4 arguments.

Comment: @gunr2171: Check my answer again.

Comment: it is an integer but when i leave it as `type` it is underlined and says that `use unassigned variable`

Comment: Then do `ElementType type = new ElementType();`

Comment: what would be my return statement?

Comment: DataType same as that of `typeContent.Children`. Because this method is assigning value to this property.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to pass in `type` instead of `type.ModelId` - `type` is an `ElementType`.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted?  I'll note that I did not copy; my answer was posted before Nikhil edited his answer from "the function only takes 3 arguments" to what it is now (which matches my answer - I'll presume he reached the same conclusion I did after he re-evaluated the question).

Comment: Yep, was just looking.  Do you have info for the `ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap` and `ElementsType`?  You see where I'm driving at - trying to find something that is of type `ElementType` that you can assign to `type`.  Doing that is where you'll find your answer (or alternatively, find out if you even need `ElementType` - you may just be able to find the id of the `ElementType`, and just pass in an int instead, since that's what the function uses).

Comment: thanks for your help :) i uploaded more for both `elementType` and `ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap `

Comment: I will be using `ModelId` which is the id of the top level category to get the content related within

Comment: Based on what I see, looks like you need to do another query that joins the `ElementModelForCourseIndex` value with the table that has the `ElementType` info in order to get the `type` member populated.  At that point, you'll have your `ModelId` that you need.

Comment: my `ElementsModelsForCourseIndexMap` for mapping the names with the table in stored procs but `Children` is the result of content from the `GetElementChildrenModelsForCourseIndex` method

Comment: In my controller i am assigning Types. I am trying to wrap my head around this it seems like all i need is there but my thought strings are knotted up in my head

Comment: I believe setting ElementType = new ElementType() did the trick but now how should my return statement look like?